# Is "within a month, sometimes sooner" redundant?

Tags: redundancy

Is this statement redundant?

> Your box will ship within a month of successful billing, sometimes sooner.

Comment: Depends on what it means.

Comment: Wouldn't "sometimes sooner" require that it shipped before it was successfully billed?

Comment: Semantically/logically yes, pragmatically no. 'Within a month' hints at a median delay of around 3 weeks; 'sometimes sooner' at a median delay of say 10 days. But these are grey areas.

Comment: Not redundant, but clashing. The bad guys are *within* and *sooner*. Within gives a range (1-31 days), and sooner says earlier. Than what? Not the start of the range, and the end is already the end. And if this is marketing material, you're shooting yourself in the foot with depressing promises that are worse than *We ship your box within a month of successful billing*.

Comment: Take out _sometimes_ and put in _or_. It's a simple mistake.

Comment: This reminds me of the sales pitch "prices up to 70% off or higher". What's 70%? "Within a month" a day, a week, or anything up to a month. In this context, "sooner" means before successful billing.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of semantics alone, *or sooner* is redundant, because it is logically implied by *within a month* (as has been already said in Ms. Bunting's answer).

However, although saying that something will happen 'within a month', so far as its meaning (in the strict sense of *meaning*) is concerned, leaves it entirely open whether it will happen on the first or the thirtieth or any of the days in between, people are more likely to use that phrase when they expect it to happen close to the end of the period. *Within a month of X* may thus be interpreted as something like 'it won't be later than a month from X, but it won't be much sooner, either'. Adding *or sooner* may be a way of cancelling that conversational implicature; it is thus not redundant as a matter of pragmatics.

Comment: I now notice that, while I was preparing this answer, Mr. Ashworth posted essentially the same answer; he, however, chose to do so in a comment.

Comment: The reason being I'd estimate 2+ hours looking for supporting references, and even then opinion plays a large part in deciding on the default usages.

Answer (score 0):

*Within a month* of something means *after a month, or less time*, so it is redundant to add *or sooner*.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like marketing language.

"within a month" means it could be shipped up to a month of successful billing. The business uses this to cover their ass if there are delays in shipping. If a customer complains about how long the delivery is taking, customer service can say that they were warned and they have no right to complain.

But adding "sometimes sooner" gives the customer hope that it won't always take that long. It implies that the company will try to deliver sooner than the month they said it could take. This is probably the more likely situation, because if they frequently take the maximum delivery time they'll get lots of bad reviews. CYA is usually intended for exceptional situations, not business as usual (because if it's BAU, they're not doing it right).